# Non-native Dialog in Qt Quick 2 application

Tags: qt, dialog, qml, qtquick2

How to make dialogs from `import QtQuick.Dialogs` to be non-native, non-`QDialog`-derived (`QFileDialog` etc)?

It is possible to make `QFileDialog` to be non-native ([`QFileDialog::Option::DontUseNativeDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html)). But how to make dialogs in *QML* to be rendered on `xcb` QPA and on `eglfs` QPA in the similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

to this

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
```

does the trick for `Dialog`, but not `FileDialog`. It essentially tells `QtQuick.Dialogs` that you're not using widgets, but it also affects the style that is used.

The code that checks which application is in use is [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qquickcontrolsettings.cpp#n59):

```
static QString defaultStyleName()
{
    //Only enable QStyle support when we are using QApplication
#if defined(QT_WIDGETS_LIB) && !defined(Q_OS_IOS) && !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) && !defined(Q_OS_BLACKBERRY) && !defined(Q_OS_QNX) && !defined(Q_OS_WINRT)
    if (QCoreApplication::instance()->inherits("QApplication"))
        return QLatin1String("Desktop");
#elif defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) && !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID_EMBEDDED)
    if (QtAndroidPrivate::androidSdkVersion() >= 11)
        return QLatin1String("Android");
#elif defined(Q_OS_IOS)
    return QLatin1String("iOS");
#elif defined(Q_OS_WINRT) && 0 // Enable once style is ready
    return QLatin1String("WinRT");
#endif
    return QLatin1String("Base");
}
```

[`void QQuickAbstractDialog::setVisible(bool)`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/dialogs/qquickabstractdialog.cpp#n79)) seems to control which type of dialog is shown. I'm not sure if there's a way to force non-native Dialogs using public QML API, but you could always patch Qt:

```
diff --git a/src/dialogs/qquickabstractdialog.cpp b/src/dialogs/qquickabstractdialog.cpp
index ce87d56..416f796 100644
--- a/src/dialogs/qquickabstractdialog.cpp
+++ b/src/dialogs/qquickabstractdialog.cpp
@@ -81,7 +81,7 @@ void QQuickAbstractDialog::setVisible(bool v)
     if (m_visible == v) return;
     m_visible = v;

-    if (m_dialogHelperInUse || v) {
+    if (0 /*m_dialogHelperInUse || v*/) {
         // To show the dialog, we first check if there is a dialog helper that can be used
         // and that show succeeds given the current configuration. Otherwise we fall back
         // to use the pure QML version.
```

This patch alone is enough to force the QML dialog implementations to be used.

For `FileDialog`, there is [this paragraph](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#details) that explains the process:

> The implementation of FileDialog will be a platform file dialog if
>   possible. If that isn't possible, then it will try to instantiate a
>   QFileDialog. If that also isn't possible, then it will fall back to a
>   QML implementation, DefaultFileDialog.qml. In that case you can
>   customize the appearance by editing this file. DefaultFileDialog.qml
>   contains a Rectangle to hold the dialog's contents, because certain
>   embedded systems do not support multiple top-level windows. When the
>   dialog becomes visible, it will automatically be wrapped in a Window
>   if possible, or simply reparented on top of the main window if there
>   can only be one window.

Comment: I need the latest fallback.

Comment: I cant use `DefaultFileDialog` directly. `QGuiApplication` does nothing.

Comment: "latest fallback"?

Comment: I mean third case, when no one previous isn't possible: `If that also isn't possible, then it will fall back to a QML implementation, DefaultFileDialog.qml.`. From your cite.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that using `QGuiApplication` works for `Dialog`, but not `FileDialog`.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I acheive desired, but your patch is not sufficient. Aslo into the next `if` you need to comment also `if (m_hasNativeWindows)` block. Then latest fallback is chosen.