# Virtual keyboard and File Dialog QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, virtual-keyboard

I have integrated **Virtual Keyboard** in my application and whenever a `TextFiled` is clicked, automatically **Virtual Keyboard** pops up but when I open a `FileDialog` and click on TextInput field inside that Virtual keyboard is not coming up.

Is there any way to open **QML Virtual keyboard** for `FileDialog`?

Comment: There's no `FileInputDialog` in Qt; which type are you referring to?

Comment: My bad sorry it's `FileDialog` ... I have updated the question ...

Comment: I could be wrong, but the keyboard might not show up if it's a proper native dialog. You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342571/904422) to see if a non-native dialog works.

Comment: Thanks !!! I read the article and i can also see that QT is using `DefaultFileDialog`in my environment/Setup. If i add/edit something in DefaultFileDialog.qml should i need to build something or if i just build my project it will work?  Please suggest.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to build Qt Quick Controls (run `make` in the `qtquickcontrols` directory). This assumes that you are building Qt yourself, though. More info on building Qt yourself: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Answer (score 0):

Better to check by declaring Inputpanel QML Type in your qml. And then just need to link with Textinput of your qml.

Comment: I have already done that and keyboard is coming up for all the text input fields.But how to link with fileinput dialog Text field ?  As there is no provision to do that .Can you please give an example ?